# Assigning null to useState()'s initial value, pass a string later. Arg of type "login" is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state

this is my code example:

```
  const [modalType, setModalType] = useState(null);

  <button onClick={() => setModalType("login")}>Log in</button>
  <button onClick={() => setModalType("register")}>Register</button>
```

This is the error that I get: `Argument of type '"login"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<null>'.` But I am not sure if it makes sense, as in other projects I used to have null as an initial value without having any problems.

Comment: @Quentin - I wish I could upvote dupe closures. :-)

Comment: change `const [modalType, setModalType] = useState(null);` to `const [modalType, setModalType] = useState<string | null>(null);`

Comment: *But I am not sure if it makes sense, as in other projects I used to have null as an initial value without having any problems."* Perhaps those were JavaScript projects. For TypeScript, if the initial value is `null`, it won't let you specify anything other than `null` without an explicit type annotation like the one @R4ncid showed you.